# How do I read the value of registers in Logism?

Tags: digital-logic, circuit-design, memory, cpu, register

I am designing a CPU in logism. One of the components of the CPU is a register circuit (RegFile), which stores the registers data. The register circuit (RegFile) is shown below:

[image]

I am able to write data to the registers as shown below:

[image]

However, I am unable to read data from the registers. The following call of the register circuit always returns 0 values for the registers, even when the registers have non-zero data in them:

[image]

When I use probes to inspect the value of A_Register and B_Register, it always shows up as 0 and any of the Reg1d, Reg2d, Reg3d, etc. outputs also show up as 0.

Comment: Can you read the data from inside the file? I presume that file is another page, or schematic.

Comment: Did you send a clock pulse?